# How to display the previous and next slider half on the screen in owl carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel-2

I am using owl carousel 2 plugin (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html). It's working perfectly. I just want to change the width of the slider so that half part of the previous slider and next slider will display on the screen.

Suggested answer(Oleg Nurutdinov) is working but not working 100%. because I used margin:300 and I am getting the output like this:https://prnt.sc/k5nptg

I need output like this
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
   center: true,
    stagePadding: 0,
   loop:true,
    margin:300,
    nav:true,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
        },
        600:{
            items:1,
        },
        1000:{
            items:1,
        }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.display_table{display: table;}
.table_cel{display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;}
.home_testimonial{background-color: #fff;}
.testi_white_box{
background-color: #fff;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 30px;
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(0,0,0,.1);

}
.testi_white_box p{font-size: 18px;padding-bottom: 30px;}
.testi_pic{width: 65px;height: 65px;border-radius: 50%;}
.testi_pic img{
border-radius: 50%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 65px;
}

.testi_names{padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;}
.testi_names h2{font-size: 22px;color:#ee220c;}
.testi_names p{font-size: 16px;}
.owl-stage{margin: 30px;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

<section class="home_testimonial">
   <div class="equal_padding">
      <div class="">
         <div class="home_testimonial_slider">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="item">
                  <div class="testi_white_box">
                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</p>
                     <div class="testi_profile display_table">
                     <div class="testi_pic table_cel"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/user_male2-512.png" class="rounded-circle"></div>
                     <div class="testi_names table_cel">
                        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
                        <p>consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <div class="testi_white_box">
                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse</p>
                     <div class="testi_profile display_table">
                     <div class="testi_pic table_cel"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/user_male2-512.png" class=""></div>
                     <div class="testi_names table_cel">
                        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
                        <p>consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <div class="testi_white_box">
                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</p>
                     <div class="testi_profile display_table">
                     <div class="testi_pic table_cel"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/user_male2-512.png" class=""></div>
                     <div class="testi_names table_cel">
                        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
                        <p>consectetur adipisicing elitt</p>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         </div>
   </div>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but it looks like this example is what you need.
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html

**UPD**

Now I'm try to do it by myself, it works like you want with this settings

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        center: true,
        stagePadding: 0,
        loop:true,
        margin:100,
        nav:true,
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1,
            },
            600:{
                items:1,
            },
            1000:{
                items:2,
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My changes is set items to 2, add center: true and set margin bigger.

Comment: Nope, I am looking something other. I need more space between each slider

Comment: Thanks for the reply @OlegSmzl, You added margin:100, in the script which is good. I added margin:300, for my designer output but the issue how do I increase the width of the current slider? You can check my output after adding the margin 300 http://prntscr.com/k5nptg

Comment: @user9437856 I have only one idea for this task is to set width: 100% то div with "testi_white_box" class. Now, value for width param is 80%.

Comment: because I added margin:300

Comment: There is output on my resolution with margin 300 and width 100% - https://prnt.sc/k5o3g9

Comment: That displaying because your screen resolution is high as compared to mine